# why is scala Collection.map versus Try.map not consistent?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

scala `collection` `map` documentation says this on `map` function:

> Builds a new collection by applying a function to **all** elements of this
>   list.

so it runs on **every** item in the collection.

but for try it says:

> Maps the given function to the value **from this Success** or returns this
>   if this is a Failure.

so it runs **only** on `success`, while i can understand nothing to run on `failure` i could still just print it.  why is it inconsistent with collection map interface? do i need to check out what `map` does on every data structure I  use and may find it behaves differently?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`map` on any monadic structure always operates on the "success case", i.e. where the data you're interested in are.

In `List` the "success case" is represented by its elements, on `Try` by the `Success` case, in `Future` the same thing, in `Option` by the `Some` case.

`List` is also little different than the others, since it doesn't really have a "failure case", like `Try`, `Future` or `Option` do (although you could consider the `Nil` list as such)

Generally speaking you can think in this terms: whenever you `map` over something, you're applying a transformation on the data held by the container on its "success case"

Comment: In the words of Eric Meijer "Monads guide you through the happy path" :).

Comment: Indeed it is a question of a collection vs monadic data type such as option, try, monadic futures, either (where one side is still considered the success in scala) etc. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_(functional_programming)

Comment: `recover` " is like map for the exception. "  http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.util.Try@recover[U%3E:T](f:PartialFunction[Throwable,U]):scala.util.Try[U]

Comment: @som-snytt - Welll, not exactly, because it maps from the failure case to the success case (only).  Mapping between throwables is probably a better candidate for "map for the exception".  But regardless of analogy, `recover` is good to know about.

Comment: @RexKerr I was just quoting the scaladoc, following the procedure of the OP. Maybe it should say: "Recover guides you back to the happy path."